# Getting 403 error with Curl for calling java web application with jsessionId

Tags: java, tomcat, curl, centos

I am running the curl command in my CentOS release 6.4 (Final) like the line below, and the requested pages are a java web application pages hosted on Tomcat7.

```
curl http://10.1.1.140:8080/tmp/tmp2000
```

in response I get some sessionId so I request for the next page like this:

```
curl http://10.1.1.140:8080/tmp/pages/next;jsessionid=71A6FC0D190AB25A63938DFCBEE26025?cbb0fc79382a4f039e6f8eb5fef8b1cd=success.filled
```

but in response I get this:

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 403 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>Access to the specified resource () has been forbidden.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.26</h3></body></html>
```

which is an error of "HTTP Status 403".

Comment: The problem is still happen, even if I set user-agent for it. for example I did this: `curl -A 'Mozilla/3.0 (Win95; I)' {my url}` and I still get the first response and get 403 Error on second request.

Comment: For the second command I used `curl --cookie "JSESSIONID=665457F8EB1FDD445BBA4886BB0E1134;" http://10.1.1.140:8080/tmp/pages/next;jsessionid=665457F8EB1FDD445BBA4886BB0E1134?cbb0fc79382a4f039e6f8eb5fef8b1cd=success.filled` and **it worked**!
But I want to use curl only and do not set cookies for every request. I want it to do it automatically since the sessionId is in the requested URL.